# How to align badge on top of icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, badge

I am trying to add badge over a fontawesome icon but it's not getting aligned properly. Whatever I try, it either comes in the top or on the below. But I am trying to add it over the icon.

Please tell me what am I missing.

Thank You!

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
.menutoggle {
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #1d2939;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}

.menutoggle i {
    padding:15px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
}

.menutoggle:hover {
    color: #1d2939;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.badge{
  display:inline-block;
  min-width:10px;
  padding:3px 7px;
  font-size:12px;
  font-weight:700;
  line-height:1;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  white-space:nowrap;
  vertical-align:baseline;
  background-color:#777;
  border-radius:10px
}
```

```html
<ul>
        <li>
           <div class="menutoggle"> 
               <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
             <span class="badge">1</span>
           </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: whats the desired position for that badge? vertically centered?

Comment: just above the icon...to the left or to the right... just like facebook notification..@Crispy-George

Comment: you will need to change the `position: absolute` or `relative` and possibly play with the `z-index`

Comment: yup the position and with the top & right worked... Thanks @MrPickles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to position badge elements relatively to their parent `menutoggle` containers. For this set `position: relative;` to `.menutoggle` and `position: absolute;` for badges with desired top and left/right values.

```css
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
.menutoggle {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 50px;
    height: 52px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #1d2939;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-out 0s;
}
.menutoggle i {
    padding:15px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.menutoggle:hover {
    color: #1d2939;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
.badge {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    min-width:10px;
    padding:3px 7px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:700;
    line-height:1;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    white-space:nowrap;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background-color:#777;
    border-radius:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="menutoggle"> 
            <i class="fa fa-cog"></i>
            <span class="badge">1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```